# How to use TrueType paid font in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, fonts, truetype

I want to use GOTHAM font in my iOS application. I see how I can drag and use the font since 3.2 but how do I license it?

http://richardwarrender.com/2010/08/custom-fonts-on-ipad-and-iphone/

How do I pay for a license for iOS? I can purchase a license for 1 CPU through here: http://www.typography.com/fonts/font_overview.php?productLineID=100008

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently had this exact discussion with H&FJ. They license a whole family (like Gotham) per app, per year. It's an add-on to the desktop license, so you'll need a legit one of those, too.

Probably not appropriate for me to say here what they quoted, but it was either completely reasonable, or completely insane, depending on what you think a font should cost. Let's just say that the pricing reflects corporate branding market economics, not small app developer economics.

Explain your use case to them in an email to oem@typography.com.

Also, I'll point out that you should look at [iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com). The list of built-in fonts is getting pretty impressive. In particular, Helvetica Neue has a ton of different weights available.

Comment: Thanks for the info!! Mind to email me the price you were quoted. I wont get an answer till Monday at least. kevin@iconentertainment.ca

Comment: I am in this boat now as well. Not sure why you can't just say what they quoted you, can you at least ballpark the price? Eg between 2-3k, more that 10k, etc

Comment: You have to pay usual the desktop license, whatever that is. Then in addition to that you need to give them another fee every year. For the fonts we wanted it was about $1K per font per app per year, although they discount for multiple fonts. And this was about 2 years ago, so the prices may have gone up since then. Also since then the roboto and other open source font families have come a long way, so I strongly recommend that you look at them as alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a commercial license for the font, if there isn't a link easily visible on the site, you should contact the author and ask him/her directly for the price and availability of a commercial license for that specific font.

A commercial license gives you the right of using the product in a commercial project of your own, and to redistribute that product within yours.